# Mean and variance regime-switching model

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-integrals

Suppose we have the following model for stock price:
$$
X_{t}=X_{0}\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{\epsilon(s)}^2)ds+\int_{0}^{t} \sigma_{\epsilon(s)}dW_{s}\right)
$$
This follows a normal distribution. How can I derivate that for the mean $m(t)$ and variance $v(t)$ yields:
$$
m(t)=\ln(X(0))+\left(rT-\frac{1}{2}v(t)\right)
$$
and
$$
v(t)=(\sigma_{0}^2-\sigma_{1}^2)t+\sigma_{1}T
$$ where $T$ is the endtime.

My first idea was to work out the integrals, but I'm stuck with that.
Hopefully anyone can help!

Comment: This is perhaps a silly question, but what is $\epsilon(s)$?